# Inadvertently upgraded Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am new to Ubuntu. It seems I inadvertently opted to upgrade the OS. I believe I have been using version 14.04 (I'm not completely sure about this.) After more than an hour of the upgrade process, it was shown that the upgrade was not completed successfully. And when I tried to reboot, I got a black screen with four options.

[image]

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Could I lose files in the hard disk if I wrongly choose one of these options, say *Restore Ubuntu 14.04 to factory state*?

Comment: Seems like 4 options to me .. just hit enter ;) usually this should be done automatically after a view seconds

Comment: @derHugo Nothing happens when I select the first option, *Ubuntu

Comment: click advanced options, see if there i a kernel availabe for you  to boot, and complete the install. If not, restore factory state. My guess is the upgrade removed the kernel you were running

Comment: @ravery Could I lose hard disk files by restoring the factory state?

Comment: I suggest that you **backup all files, that you cannot afford to lose**, before I try the restore option.

Comment: I don't know if /home folder is safe or not. if it does not format partitions it will be safe. use a LiveCD to backup data is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the upgrade was not completed successfully, your best option is to reinstall fresh. While 'restore' might work, it may not fix whatever problem originally caused the release-upgrade to fail.

1) Create an Ubuntu LiveUSB stick using a different computer

2) Boot from the LiveUSB. Select "Try Ubuntu"

3) Mount your Hard Drive, and copy your /home onto some other backup media.

4) Use the LiveUSB to install a fresh version of Ubuntu onto your system.

5) Reboot into the new version of Ubuntu.

6) If needed, mount your backup and copy the contents back to your /home.

A failed upgrade usually happens for one of the following reasons:

- Non-Ubuntu software (by far the most frequent). Good practice is to remove non-Ubuntu software and sources before upgrading to another release of Ubuntu.
- Network failure
- Power failure